# Selenium webdriver not locating element via object repository file

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am searching for an element in selenium webdriver, via an object file.  All other elements are getting returned, apart from one.  I have tried configuring the locator to xpath, cssselector and name etc.

When I try to locate the element directly from the console by id or any other locator, it is located successfully. Just not via the object file.

All information is correct in the object file and in console

Here is object file content:

```
one=.//*[@id='1'] 
two=.//*[@id='2'] 
three=.//*[@id='3']
four=.//*[@id='4'] 
five=.//*[@id='5'] 
six=.//*[@id='6'] 
seven=.//*[@id='7'] 
eight=.//*[@id='8'] 
nine=.//*[@id='9']
zero=.//*[@id='0']
equalsto=.//*[@id='equals'] 
cler=.//*[@id='AC']
result=.//*[@id='Resultbox']
plus=.//*[@id='plus'] 
minus=.//*[@id='minus'] 
mul=.//*[@id='multiply']
heading=.//*[@id='Blog1']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/h3
```

Here is code:

```
public class CalcTest {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void openbrowser() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/04/calc.html");
    }

    /*@AfterMethod
    public void closebrowser() {
        driver.quit();
    }*/

    @Test
    public void Calc_Operations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Create Object of Properties Class.
        Properties obj = new Properties();
        // Create Object of FileInputStream Class. Pass file path.
        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Objects\\objects.properties");
        // Pass object reference objfile to load method of Properties object.
        obj.load(objfile);

        // Sum operation on calculator.
        // Accessing element locators of all web elements using
        // obj.getProperty(key)

        String heading = driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("heading"))).getText();
        System.out.println(heading);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("eight"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("plus"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("four"))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("equalsto"))).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(("result"))).getAttribute("value");

        //String i = driver.findElement(By.name(obj.getProperty("result"))).getAttribute("value");
        //System.out.println(i);
        //System.out.println(obj.getProperty("eight") + " + " + obj.getProperty("four") + " = " + i);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("result"))).clear();
```

Comment: This is going to be edited in 3...2...1...

Comment: please provide exception..

Comment: whats exception you are getting ?? and where in your code, your searching for one  -- i don't see that ... please post the correct code.

Comment: The problem is with the 'result' locator.  I have tried using id, cssSelector, name etc...  All fail when searching via the object file (only for result locator).  Exception = Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"result"}. However, if I search directly in eclipse for the element using any locator, it works!!!!!

Comment: I had a similar issue with locating the eight - I was searching via id.  When I searched directly on eclipse for id - it worked.  Had to change to search via xpath.  Has anyone else encountered issues locating elements via an object repository file?